# How to change an existing table selection mode from single to multiple

Tags: r, shiny, dt

How do I change the DT::datatable selection of an existing table (not a new table)?

(updated) Here is a simple example, when the user clicks on the input$change_selection, I want to update tbl so that its selection is multiple

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(actionButton("change_selection", label = "Change selection"), DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$change_selection, {
      # code to change the tbl selection from single to multiple
    })
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, selection = list(mode = 'single', target = 'row'), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

I'm using DT version 0.23 and can upgrade if needed...

I have searched for the answer but haven't found a way and all help is appreciated...

Comment: Could your provide example code, data, and expected output?

Comment: ok, i added a simple and working example code above; it use the iris data and i expect when the "Change selection" button is pressed, the table selection mode be changed from single to multiple...

Comment: Yaa,I found the answer [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590704/1769758)